# Unity2D - Changing rotation direction using transform.RotateAround()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I am making a simple game where two moons orbit around a planet. I want to make it so that with the press of a button:

```
    public KeyCode switch_rotation_moon_a;
    private bool rotating_left = false;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(switch_rotation_moon_a))
        {
            rotating_left = !rotating_left;
        }
    }
```

where rotating_left is what decides the rotation direction. I then have this for the actual implementation of the rotation:

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        planet_position = radius * Vector3.Normalize(this.transform.position - planet.transform.position) + planet.transform.position;
        this.transform.position = planet_position;
        if (rotating_left)
        {
            transform.RotateAround(planet.transform.position, new Vector3(0, 0, 1),  rotation_speed);
        }
        transform.RotateAround(planet.transform.position, new Vector3(0, 0, -1), rotation_speed);
    }
```

When starting the game, the planet seems to rotate just fine in one direction, but inverting the z-axis just stops the rotation.

I've looked into transform.RotateAround(), but I have a hard time understanding the exact math behind it. I would also appreciate a simple explanation of the math behind it, I don't expect ready-to-copy code! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `else`, i.e.:

```
if (rotating_left)
{
    transform.RotateAround(planet.transform.position, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), rotation_speed);
}
else
{
    transform.RotateAround(planet.transform.position, new Vector3(0, 0, -1), rotation_speed);
}
```

Your current code is running both rotations at the same time when `rotating_left` is true, causing them to cancel each other out.

As for the maths, under the hood the rotations in Unity are likely fairly complicated, since internally they're represented as Quaternions. As a developer though, Tranform.RotateAround simply Rotates the transform about `axis` passing through `point` in world coordinates by `angle` degrees (from https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html).

Unity uses a left-handed coordinate system, meaning if you hold your left hand out, with your thumb going in the direction of the axis you're rotating around, and close your fist, a positive angle will rotate in the direction your fingers are facing.

Comment: Wow, did not expect it to be something this trivial. Thanks a lot for pointing it out! :D

Comment: @MickyD I did forget that yeah.

I'm not sure what math they'd be after though. I imagine they thought it wasn't working because it was more complicated than it actually is.

Comment: No worries. +1 nonetheless. :)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to add a simple explanation of what Transform.RotateAround does, though there's no math in my explanation haha

Answer (score 1):

In addition to jdewi:

Please consider, less is more:

```
...
private float direction = 1.0f
private void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(switch_rotation_moon_a))
        direction = -direction;

}

private void FixedUpdate()
{

    ...

    transform.RotateAround(planet.transform.position, new Vector3(0, 0, direction),  rotation_speed);

}
```

This saves an if statement and so a check. The direction will be reversed on key down, and so the rotation too.